# Identify amplifier or transistor

Tags: identification, reverse-engineering

I am trying to repair a PCB that controls a camping fridge, in the process of reverse engineering the circuit I have got stuck at the device in the top left of the below photo marked K17h I believe this is either a transistor or op-amp used to amplify the voltage drop from the large shunt to the right.

Is there any way I can identify this component, and ideally find a pinout? I have searched for K17h but turned up nothing. Is there a database of these SMD codes kept anywhere for reverse engineering purposes?

[image: Close up]

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a SD5054 lithium battery charge manager by Shouding.

It looked like a sot-23-5 package to me so I found this [product page](https://www.yoycart.com/Product/565425389233/)
by searching on google: "k17h" sot-23-5.

In the [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1804141011_SHOUDING-SD5054_C171626.pdf) you'll find some info (in chinese) about the naming of this chip. It says there:

> k1XY
>
> XY=日期代码

In google translate "日期代码" translates to "Date code"

To answer your question about a database for SMD codes, you'll find some smd code books on google, for example [this book](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/mainframe.htm) which I sometimes use.

Comment: so XY=7h = 2017 8th month

Comment: I don't think this is the component, unless it is being used in a creative way. There isn't any lithium batteries in this product, I believe this is being used to monitor for over-current of a cooling fan. That SMD codes link looks very handy and I have bookmarked it even though it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: My guess is comparator. Top two pins being in plus and minus, one of the bottom ones being output...